# Statistics by day and month (php)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make statistics for my website by days and month & years
I think to make date() function

Well, First I create a database that has 3 col

Id
date
statistics

For example today we are 27-05-2016, So, the database has

1 | 27-05-2016 | 5

and when I have a new day that insert a new row for example

2 | 28-05-2016 | 20

and I showed result with while ... etc

but I have a problem I want to know how when the day finished I insert new day ? How I can Automatically if the day ended I insert new date for the new day ?

Comment: Just create the days in advance, for the next 5 years. In your queries you can use today's date to exclude the future dates.

Comment: So, There isn't any functions to make days automatically ?

Comment: I am just suggesting to make your life easy. Anything that is "automatic" can fail. One way is to schedule a job on the server (but if you don't own the server, that will be an issue) that runs a script inserting the record for you. But what if for some reason the job doesn't run? Are you going to check the logs? Just make your life easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the latest date from database, `SELECT * FROM stat_table ORDER BY date DESC;`

Keep latest date in a variable $latest_date = $data['date'];

```
  if (current_date = $latest_date) {
    update database
  } else {
    insert new row
  }
```

Comment: I think that's perfect I will try it

Comment: Techically `if (current_date = $latest_date)` will fail as it is an assignment `=` rather than a comparison `==`, which should read as `if (current_date == $latest_date)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not *too* good with php but im pretty sure the best you can do is wait for an interaction(logging in ect), and then check the time and compare it with the last logged time. So for example. jDoe787 logged in at 6:56 AM 1/5/16 the logges right back out.(Here the server updates the last time someone logged in) jDoe logs in later at 12:01 AM, a script turns on as a it is a different day then the one he last logged so it changes the database to the new day, and does whatever it needs to

Comment: but I don't need someone to login, I want to make statistics

Comment: Just an example of someone doing an action. It could be used in other ways

Answer (score 0):

Try to use REPLACE INTO operator. But first you have to make a UNIQUE index on your DATE field

Comment: Perhaps giving a clear example would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always run the update query with current date and if the update returns false then insert the new entry

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a table with one row for each distinct date, and you want to update your `statistics` column with new data.

You can do this cleanly in MySQL, using some MySQL-specific extensions.

First, you create your table and put a `UNIQUE INDEX` on your `date` column. This kind of table definition does the trick. (This is standard SQL.)

```
CREATE TABLE `stat` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `statistics` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `date_index` (`date`)
);
```

Notice that, with this definition, an attempt to `INSERT` a duplicate `date` value will fail.  But that's good, because MySQL has the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` syntax. (This is MySQL-specific.)

To insert a new row for the current date if necessary, and otherwise to add one to the current date's `statistics` column, you can use this statement:

```
INSERT INTO stat (date,statistics) VALUES (CURDATE(), 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statistics = statistics+1;
```

The first line of this statement creates a row in the `stat` table and sets the `statistics` column to `1`. The second line increments `statistics` if the row already exists.

Notice one other thing: the `id` column is not strictly necessary. You can use the `date` column as the primary key. This table definition will work well for you.

```
CREATE TABLE `stat` (
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `statistics` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);
```